# Pass the value of variable to calling java code from .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have the following scenario.

Java --> main.bat --> sub.bat
sub.bat--> main.bat-->java

```
the main.bat looks something like this
call sub.bat c:\sample.txt value1
echo %value1% <--does not work
echo Hello World <--works
```

the sub.bat returns the value in value1 variable.

now the java code is executing the main.bat and trying to read the value of variable value1.
   however the java code works fine when main.bat does echo Hello World.
   however it doesnt work if the main.bat has echo %value1%

please let me know whats wrong with the code.

Comment: Try `echo %2`, which in batch will give you the 2nd parameter

Comment: Where are the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Try running main.bat directly from command line to find out why your code is not working

Comment: the main.bat works from the command line. however it does not return a value to the java code.